# Class not defined in validation.js after upgrade to 1.9.4.0?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I updated from **1.9.3.7 to 1.9.4.0** using the .mage command line tool. Everything works fine in the admin, the frontend however always shows me `Class is not defined`. The code where this happens is in validation.js and looks like this:

```
var Validator = Class.create();
```

I checked that prototype.js is loaded before validation.js an it is, so that is not the problem I guess. Any other ideas why that happens? I cleared all the caches and I do not merge JS.

Comment: did you find the solutions?